# Windows 10 no internet on one network

Tags: windows-10, networking, wifi-configuration, ip-address, windows-networking

I have a problem which I cannot figure out. My laptop has no issues connecting to a couple of wifi networks, except for 1 network which it connects but has no internet. Other devices do get internet through that network.

I tried the following commands:

ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh int reset
netsh winsock reset

I also tried windows 10 network reset.
I tried setting a manual ip address and dhcp. I cannot get it to work.
Ping errors out as well. Even when I ping local gateway. Pinging the address of a printer on the network does work.
Status shows the network connected and traffic flowing, but it doesn't route through to the internet.

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: What were the outputs of those commands.  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Is there any error message when you access the Internet? Try to set a fixed DNS server. Enter for preferred DNS server as 8.8.8.8.

Comment: @Sunny I set the dns as 8.8.8.8. it doesn't help. It seems like it is not reaching the gateway